# method and final modifiers

Tags: java, swing, methods, final

So, I have a JTextArea. I have added keyboard action to it's input/action maps.

On enter press, JDialog is supposed to be created, along with it's contents. And I need to add keyListener to a button it will contain, which i can't, because that button doesn't ahve final modifier. If I set it to final, I can't edit it's properties.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
class blabla extends JTextArea
{
getInputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"), "pressedEnter");
getActionMap.put("pressedEnter", new AbstractAction()
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                JDialog dialog;
                JButton confirm;;

                //JDialog
                dialog = new JDialog(Main.masterWindow, "newTitle", true);
                dialog.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(dialog.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
                dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
                {
                    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e)
                    {
                        //this doen't work, it asks me to declare confirm as final
                        //and I have to request focuse here due to Java bug
                        confirm.requestFocus();
                    }
                });

                //JButton for confirming
                confirm = new JButton(lang.getString("ok"));
                confirm.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

                confirm.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
                    {
                        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                        {
                            //this doen't work, it asks me to declare confirm as final
                            confirm.doClick();
                        }
                    }       
                });

                dialog.add(confirm);

                dialog.pack();
                dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(Main.masterWindow);
                dialog.setVisible(true);
}
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Option 1: make confirm a class field.
- Option 2: You could create a dummy final JButton variable, `final JButton finalConfirm = confirm;` and pass in the confirm reference, and then work on this variable inside of the inner class.
- Option 3: don't use an anonymous inner class for your Key Binding's AbstractAction, but rather a private inner class with a constructor that takes the JButton instance.

Comment: Also, use an `Action` for `confirm`, and consider using the root pane's `getDefaultButton()`.